# Python 2.7 How to Print unicode-escape format string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

I knew unicode string in python, is like u"blablabla". It should start with "u" character.
But I found some "unicode" like strings from some api, it's like

```
{"ret":"100015","msg":"\u5bc6\u7801\u8f93\u5165\u9519\u8bef\uff0c\u8fd8\u53ef\u4ee5\u8f93\u51654\u6b21","msg_new":"\u5bc6\u7801\u8f93\u5165\u9519\u8bef<br>\u8fd8\u53ef\u4ee5\u8f93\u5165<b>4<\/b>\u6b21"}
```

The string does not start with "u" character, so I wonder how I can process these strings?

Comment: That looks like a `json` string, try passing the result into `json.loads()`.

Comment: It's a json string. But what I want to know, is how to handle string like "\u5bc6\u7801\u8f93\u5165\u9519\u8bef\uff0c\u8fd8\u53ef\u4ee5\u8f93\u51654\u6b21" in python, which encoded in unicode but not with "u" character.

Comment: @xg.d What exactly do you have ? Is it a dictionary? If so, what does `print(msg)` or `print(msg_new)` give you?

Comment: Thanks. I believe @metatoaster give what I want. Thank you.

Comment: @xg.d Just FYI, the string in your example is not utf-8 encoded. It is simply a python str object.

Comment: @abc actually, it's ambiguous because it isn't assigned to some variable nor encoded in a code block.  It could be a python dictionary, JSON object, or a string.  Though the newline between `\u8bef` and `\u8fd8` throws everything off.

Comment: @xg.d: You handle it with `json.loads`, which will parse JSON unicode escapes for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a given `str` (in python 3, `bytes`) with characters encoded in the `\uHHHH` form (unicode character escape sequence), one can decode that using the `unicode-escape` codec.

```
>>> s = "\u5bc6\u7801\u8f93\u5165\u9519\u8bef\uff0c\u8fd8\u53ef\u4ee5\u8f93\u51654\u6b21"
>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>
>>> r = s.decode("unicode-escape")
>>> type(r)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print(r)
密码输入错误，还可以输入4次
```

Comment: @dawg probably because this is duplicated elsewhere but I couldn't find it quickly enough.  Might as well just help since the new question is specifically about the "escaping" the unicode escape encoding but questioner just didn't know what the technical terms are.  Would have appreciated the downvoter to point out what the duplicate post is.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but for decoding the data in the question, `unicode-escape` definitely isn't the right tool. As you said in the comments, this is JSON, and `json.loads` is the way to go. You can see things like `\/` in the data that would appear in a `print`-ed JSON string, but not a `print`-ed dict. If you pass the JSON through `unicode-escape`, you'll still have JSON instead of a useable data structure, you'll still need to `json.loads` it, and worse, you might have decoded something like `\u0022` into `"` and broken the JSON format.

Comment: @user2357112 I supposed if the questioner had edited this following comment into the question: It's a json string. But what I want to know, is how to handle string like "\u5bc6...\u6b21‌​" in python, which encoded in unicode but not with "u" character, this would have been a lot more clear on what I ended up answering.

Comment: @metatoaster: Yeah, but in that case, jumping to `unicode-escape` still isn't the right thing to do. If you have a string with unicode escapes in it, you need to figure out why before you try to decode it. It's very rarely *just* unicode escapes, and passing it through `unicode-escape` will usually lead to half-parsed or double-parsed data.

Comment: @user2357112 You do realize I pointed the facts associated with this case out in the very first comment I made against the question, then user switch to the other question but whatever, it's a duplicate.